# How to double escape double quote?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Say I have this String in java:

```
This a "text". This is inches 30". And another 20\"
```

I want to find all inches (double quotes after a number) and add a second escape for it, if it doesn't have yet.

So after the change, the string would be like this, printed in console:

```
This is a "text". This is inches 30\". And another 20\"
```

So the regex must check if there is a number before the double quote and if there is not a escape character already...

thanks!!

Comment: There wouldn't be a ``\`` after the `30`.

Comment: Be careful with this.  You don't need to escape " in a string, just in string constant you type in the program.  It doesn't make sense to me that you want to \ quote anything in a string you already have in a variable.

Comment: I will use this string in another place that will need to have the inches with a "fake" escape included. But it doesn't matter what I need it for, I'm very confused on how to do that, if someone could help I appreciate. Thanks

Comment: FYI, Unicode codepoint U+2033 (″) can be used to specify inches, so just replacing it with `"\u2033"` should suffice to marshal it through other escaping layers or to distinguish it from matched pairs of quotation marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [**`Positive Lookbehind`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
String str="This a \"text\". This is inches 30\". And another 20\\\"";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\"", "\\\\\""));
```

output:

```
This a "text". This is inches 30\". And another 20\"
```

---

Here is [Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH2gW1/9) as well.

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    \d                       digits (0-9)
  )                        end of look-behind
  \"                       '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         x='This a "text". This is inches 30". And another 20\"'
         print re.sub(r"(\d+)(\")",r"\1\\\2",x)
```

This is in python.I dont know the exact match for java.

Comment: Or just (\d)" -> \1\\"

Comment: no that would be wrong.Cos if already it is escaped we dont want to do it again./20--> would bcome //20.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to say but `re.sub(r"(\d+)(\")",r"\1\\\2"` should be the exact same as `re.sub(r'(\d)"',r'\1\\"'`